# Multiplying string by a const int C++

Tags: c++, string, multiplication

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   
   //declaring cin inputs
   string userName;
   string userMiles;
   string userSteps;
   
   
   //declaring constant for number of steps/mile
   const int stepsPerMile = 2000;   
      
      //getting user's name
      cout << "What is the user's name?";
      cin >> userName;
      cout << endl;
      
      //getting miles walked
      cout << "How many miles did " << userName << " hike today?";
      cin >> userMiles;
      cout << endl;
      
      //getting other steps taken
      cout << "How many other steps did " << userName << " take today?";
      cin >> userSteps;
      cout << endl;
      
   string stepsTakenFromMiles;
   string totalSteps;
      
   stepsTakenFromMiles = userMiles * stepsPerMile;
   totalSteps = stepsTakenFromMiles + userSteps;
   
      cout << userName << " took " << totalSteps << " steps throughout the day." << endl;
      
   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to multiply userMiles (string) by stepsPerMile (const int) and I keep getting an error that they are not matching operand types. I have to use stepsPerMile as a const int and cannot change it. How do I change my code to allow both of these inputs to be multiplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in `userMiles` and `userSteps` as integers, not as strings. `operator>>` can read in many different types, not just `std::string`. Try using `int` instead, to match your `stepsPerMile` constant, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   
   //declaring cin inputs
   string userName;
   int userMiles;
   int userSteps;
   
   //declaring constant for number of steps/mile
   const int stepsPerMile = 2000;   
      
   //getting user's name
   cout << "What is the user's name?";
   cin >> userName;
   cout << endl;
      
   //getting miles walked
   cout << "How many miles did " << userName << " hike today?";
   cin >> userMiles;
   cout << endl;
      
   //getting other steps taken
   cout << "How many other steps did " << userName << " take today?";
   cin >> userSteps;
   cout << endl;
      
   int stepsTakenFromMiles;
   int totalSteps;
      
   stepsTakenFromMiles = userMiles * stepsPerMile;
   totalSteps = stepsTakenFromMiles + userSteps;
   
   cout << userName << " took " << totalSteps << " steps throughout the day." << endl;
      
   return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mxwi2y)

Answer (score 0):

a nice program I checked it out. Cool program, I like it. I think to solve this problem. Instead of making `userMiles` a string, make it an int like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   
   //declaring cin inputs
   string userName;
   int userMiles;
   string userSteps;
   
   
   //declaring constant for number of steps/mile
   const int stepsPerMile = 2000;   
      
      //getting user's name
      cout << "What is the user's name?";
      cin >> userName;
      cout << endl;
      
      //getting miles walked
      cout << "How many miles did " << userName << " hike today?";
      cin >> userMiles;
      cout << endl;
      
      //getting other steps taken
      cout << "How many other steps did " << userName << " take today?";
      cin >> userSteps;
      cout << endl;
      
   string stepsTakenFromMiles;
   string totalSteps;
      
   stepsTakenFromMiles = userMiles * stepsPerMile;
   totalSteps = stepsTakenFromMiles + userSteps;
   
      cout << userName << " took " << totalSteps << " steps throughout the day." << endl;
      
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your identifiers

> int userMiles, userMiles;

because in C++ you can't use the multiplication operator with strings, this can be actually used in other programming languages such as python like when you multiply a string by a number the string will be repeated but in C++ you can't use arithmetic operators with string except "+" which can be used to join 2 or more strings.
[This is a c++ course for beginners check it hope it helps](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:NYUx+CPP.PRG.1+3T2020/home)